# Question about the definition of random variable

Tags: probability

I have the following definition of a random variable

[image]

Can someone please explain to me the significance on the condition?

I should say that $\Omega$ is the sample space, $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$ and that $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: The significance is that $X$ has to be a function which is "somewhat nicely behaved" (i.e measurable) rather than completely arbitrary. FOr example, we want to be able to talk about expected values, variances etc. These are all integrals of some sort, and to define integration, we need some sort of nice behavior of the functions.

Comment: Dear @peek-a-boo, thank you for the comment. Could you elaborate on what you mean by measurable?

Comment: See wikipedia [Measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function). In your specific case, you're considering real-valued functions, and on the target space you're considering what is known as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in probability theory we have to restrict ourselves to certain regularity conditions to ensure we can perform certain operations.
For example, the expectation $\mathbb E[X]$ would likely not be defined if the set $\left\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega) \leq x\right\}$ were not *measurable*.
In theory, one could define a random variable more loosely, but then every theorem about expectations or probabilities of random variables would need to be prefaced with "assuming that $\left\{X \leq x\right\}$ is measurable for all $x$..." or something.